# Django ORM: Models with 2 table referencing each other

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have 2 tables. User and Group. 1:Many relationship. Each user can only belong to a single group.

here's the model.py.

```
class Group(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    group_description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    group_creator = models.ForeignKey(User, models.DO_NOTHING)

class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ...
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, models.DO_NOTHING)
```

The issue I have is that they are both referencing each other which is acceptable in MySQL and Oracle, but, I get an error when migrating:

> group_creator = models.ForeignKey(User, models.DO_NOTHING)
>   NameError: name 'User' is not defined

Now when I reverse the order (so, User first than Group), I get

> group = models.ForeignKey(Group, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
>   NameError: name 'Group' is not defined

This is getting quite frustrating. I have a few work around (make it a many:many and keep creator on Group class), but before I start destroying my datamodel and move data move all the data around, I wonder if anyone has this issue before. How did you solve this? Do you really have to change your datamodel?

Comment: You can put quote around User and Group in ForeignKey definition.
for example:
group = models.ForeignKey('Group', models.DO_NOTHING)

Answer (score 2):

as Pourfar mentioned in a comment, you may avoid the `NameError` via the quoting the model object as string. also it is safe to set `related_name` for accessing this relation.

```
class Group(models.Model):
    ...
    group_creator = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='creator_set')
```

and then, with your constraint,

> Each user can only belong to a single group.

in that case, `OneToOneField` is more appropriate.

```
class User(models.Model):
    ...
    group = models.OneToOneField(Group)
```

then you can access the relations as follows:

```
# USER is a User object
GROUP_BELONGED = USER.group # access to 1-1 relation
GROUP_CREATED = USER.creator_set.all() # reverse access to foreignkey relation
# now GROUP_BELONGED is a Group object
CREATOR = GROUP_BELONGED.group_creator # access to foreignkey relation
```

Comment: I would like to +1 this answer but I am a noob to stackoverflow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add `related_name` to your **ForeignKey** fields:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    group_description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    group_creator = models.ForeignKey('User',related_name='myUser')

class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    group = models.ForeignKey('Group', related_name='MyGroup')
```